# How to kill all TCP connections for a specific port and PID in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I need to do some tests that involve killing the connection to one specific application that I can identify by PID and TCP port. Tcpkill allows to filter by port but not by PID.

At the moment I have no root / sudo permissions so netstat does not show PID information.

Comment: If you are truely needing to do things such as terminate process or kill connnections, you are likely going to need admin/root/sudo access to do so.